# How to use region-growing algorithms to define a region of interest?

Tags: c++, vtk, dicom, itk

I am working on DICOM images (CT scans) & would like to isolate some structures of interest in my picture such as human organs (like the aorta, cf the image enclosed). I am coding in C++ with the help of ITK & VTK.

[image: The bright tube describes a sick aorta and corresponds to the structure that I would like to isolate.]

Let's assume these organs have a particular brightness intensity, therefore I can automatically identify them by using a region-growing algorithm (code below). In order to do so, I previously computed some threshold values based on the mean & standard deviation values of the voxels belonging to the organ.

**How can I only keep the aorta in my image with the help of ITK/VTK features?** I guess that what I'm looking for is a filter that would do the exact opposite of the [ITK mask image filter](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1MaskImageFilter.html).

Please find the (pseudo) code corresponding to the organ isolation below. I computed a 5 voxels dilation on the result of the region-growing to be sure to include all voxels of the organ and to have a sufficient margin around the organ after cropping.

```
typedef short InputPixelType;
typedef unsigned char OutputPixelType; 
const int Dimension = 3;

typedef itk::Image< InputPixelType, Dimension > InputImageType;
typedef itk::Image< OutputPixelType, Dimension > OutputImageType;

// Region growing
typedef itk::ConnectedThresholdImageFilter< InputImagetype, 
OutputImagetype > ConnectedFilterType;

ConnectedFilterType::Pointer connectedThreshold = ConnectedFilterType::New();

connectedThreshold->SetInput(input);
connectedThreshold->SetUpper(upperThreshold);
connectedThreshold->SetLower(lowerThreshold);

//Initializing seed
InternalImagetype::IndexType index;
index[0] = seed_x; 
index[1] = seed_y;
connectedThreshold->SetSeed(index);

// Dilate the resulting region-growing of 5 voxels for safety
typedef itk::BinaryBallStructuringElement< OutputImageType, 
Dimension > StructuringElementType;
typedef itk::BinaryDilateImageFilter< OutputImageType, 
OutputImageType, StruturingElementType > DilateFilterType;

StructuringElementType structuringElement;
structuringElement.SetRadius(5);
structuringElement.CreateStructuringElement();

DilateFilterType::Pointer dilateFilter = DilateFilterType::New();
dilateFilter->SetInput(connectedThreshold->GetOutput());
dilatefilter->SetKernel(structuringElement);

// Saving the results of the RG+dilation
typedef itk::ImageFileWriter< OutputImageType > WriterType;
WriterType::Pointer writer = WriterType::New();
writer->SetInput(dilateFilter->GetOutput());
writer->SetFileName("organ-segmented-with-dilation.mhd");
try {
    writer->Update();
} catch(itk::ExceptionObject& err) {
    std::cerr << "Exception caught! " << err.what() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

// What to do next to crop the input image with this region-growing?
```

Any help or remark is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I solved my problem using the [ITK mask negated filter](https://itk.org/Doxygen43/html/classitk_1_1MaskNegatedImageFilter.html), which contrarily to the basic mask filter directly answers the issue.

Answer (score 1):

[Mask filter](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1MaskImageFilter.html) itself can do the opposite of what it usually does. By default, masking value is 0, and so is outside value. This means that parts of image which correspond to non-zero part of the mask are kept, and the rest is zeroed out. If this is not what you want, you can easily invert the logic by setting different masking and outside values.

Comment: Actually I have found the itkMaskNegatedImageFilter which does exaclty what I was looking for. I have also thought about what you proposed but couldn't manage to do it, I don't know why. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Perhaps vote up the answer and/or mark it as solution?